# How to store capacity number in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm making an application in which users has capacity depending on their current pricing plan. User can buy extra capacity on its own. I wondering how designed the database should be.

I'm considering two ways:

1. In the `user` table, each user has `capacity` column. The `capacity` property is updating on eg. changing plan or buying extra capacity. The value is always current.
2. The `user` table hasn't capacity column, but the capacity is stored in `plan` table – each user is linked to which plan. We also have `extra_capacity` table, there is capacity which user bought. In this case we have to make relations to those tables and count capacity.

Which way is better? Second example is more flexible but is also more complicated, so would go with first example.

Comment: What's the problem with approach 1?

Comment: Managing redundant data can end up being a more complex solution.

Comment: There is any problem, I would take first, but my friend prefers the second

Comment: I would say 2 because is more future proof. In that way if you change the plans you just change 1 table and not all the users in the DB